# Ocultar contenido por url

Tags: php, html5

quisiera saber como puedo ocultar un contenido de una página web si es que se intenta visualizar con la dirección ip.

Me explico-
Tengo 2 servidores, uno de pruebas y otro en funcionamiento, quiero que si se accede por el de pruebas un contenido desaparezca de todas las páginas que se ramifican de esta, pero en el servidor en linea si se vea.

Mi idea es la siguiente

```
<?php
 $urlbd = [Query donde saco la ip de la base de datos]
 $url = [Se coloca la ip del servidor de pruebas]
 if( $url ><  $urlbd ){
                        ?>
<label>Si son diferentes esto debe verse </label>

<?php } else { ?>
<label>Si son iguales esto debe verse</label>
<?php } ?>
```

En teoría debería funcionar, pero no sé como hacerlo para las demás páginas, por ejemplo la ip/tareas.
No sé si me doy a entender.
Gracias de ante mano y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Se podría intentar algo de la siguiente manera, donde colocas las IPs que son permitidas para ver el contenido. De esa manera lo podés adaptar a lo que estás buscando.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT ip FROM nombredetubase";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['ip'] == "127.0.0.1") 
    {
        $content1 = "display:none";
    }
    else // condicion
    {
        $content2 = "display:none";
    }   
}
?>

<div id="content1"> <?php echo $content1; ?> </div>

<div id="content2"> <?php echo $content2; ?> </div>
```